# Data storage option that best suits for my android app purpose

Tags: android, storage

I am creating an android app that can be used by common users and also admin.
Suppose, if admin adds a new place name, that name should be added to database and when common user uses the app, he should be able to see the place name that is added.

I used MySqlLite database. But the problem is that if the app is uninstalled all data is lost. So I want some persistent data storage in which all the places that are added by admin are saved permanently.

Regards,
Sindhu

Comment: Does the data need to be used across multiple devices?

Comment: yes @MichaelStoddart

Comment: If what @MichaelStoddart said is the case, you could look into Firebase Database and see if it suits your needs.

Comment: @Lev good suggestion, did not think of that, what is the pricing like on it?

Comment: @MichaelStoddart I don't know, I think it should be free up to some point but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: @Lev Thanks. I think firebase suits my purpose. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the data being needed across multiple devices, your only option is to create/use a backend API.

Parse would have been a good choice but since that is getting shut down soon then it wouldn't be wise to use that.

Take a look at [these alternatives](https://www.quora.com/What-alternatives-exist-to-Parse-now-that-it-is-shutting-down) here

You could also write one yourself, but unless you have some experience in that sort of thing then it will take some time to learn.

Comment: Thanks. I choose Firebase. Free version is sufficient for me anyhow. : )